# Using expressions in ngModel in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Giving the code inside of my controller:

```js
$scope.entity = {
  firstName: 'Jack',
  lastName: 'Bauer',
  location: {
    city: 'New York'
  }
};
$scope.path = 'location.city';
```

How do I dynamically bind `ngModel` to the property of the `entity` specified by `path`?

I've tried something like this, but to no avail:

```html
<input ng-model="'entity.' + path">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slava, I'm not too sure if this is a good idea to begin with. But anyhow,
You need to make your model getterSetter aware by adding this property to your input `ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }`. 
Then you need a function in your controller that builds a getterSetter out of a sting.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="propertify('entity.' + path)" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }">
```

That's how the resulting template would look.

Luckily angular has an $parse service that makes this a lot easier. so something like this would need to be in your controller, or even better in a injected service.

```
  $scope.propertify = function (string) {
      var p = $parse(string);
      var s = p.assign;
      return function(newVal) {
          if (newVal) {
              s($scope,newVal);
          }
          return p($scope);
      } ;
  };
```

That will return a getter-setter function that handles this for you.
see it in action in [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xk7arDkd2PgGL39jCw40?p=preview)

Comment: Sander, you are an Angular-ninja for real, thank you very much! = )

Comment: I'm still getting the "non-assignable" error with this... but your plunkr is working fine 

Comment: I had the wrong angular version  - everything's working great, thank you!

Comment: one thing I'd do different is to use `if(angular.isDefined(newVal)) {}` so empty values are assigned as well, like `false` or `""`

Comment: Great solution! Unfortunately it does not recognize array expressions like `data.model.step[0].theText`, `data.model.step[1].theText`. It automatically converts the numbers 0, 1, 2 into object keys instead of making it an array.

Answer (score 7):

## Update

It's not working as expected, the value is displayed correctly, but can not be changed. The correct solution is provided by Sander [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162197/1056679).

---

## Incorrect solution

Wow, solved it accidentally:

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="$eval('entity.' + path)">
```

And here's the [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/FeYTYPr9QVz1mOBCrJEL?p=preview).

I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the bracket notation with a little modification, as you want to bind to a nested property. You have to split the *path* to the property:

```
<input ng-model="entity[locationKey][cityKey]"/>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.locationKey = 'location';
$scope.cityKey = 'city';
```

See **[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pthts4o1/)**

Comment: Thank you, but it won't do, I store the full path in a single variable, that is the core of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

After reading and using Sander Elias' answer, I was using this, but ran into another problem.

When combining his result with `ng-required="true"` in the `<input>` you could not empty the field, because when the field would be empty, the `newVal` is passed as `undefined`.

After some more research, I found [an isssue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11361#issuecomment-84022489) that addresses and solves this problem.

Here is what Sander's and the GitHub answer combined look like:

```
$scope.propertify = function (string) {
    var property = $parse(string);
    var propAssign = property.assign;
    return function (newVal) {
        if (arguments.length) {
            newVal = angular.isDefined(newVal)?  newVal : '';
            propAssign($scope, newVal);
        }
        return property($scope);
    };
};
```

The `argument.length` reflects the number of values that are passed to the getter/setter and will be `0` on a get and `1` on a set.

Besided that, I added the `angular.isDefined()` as [Sumit suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153769/using-expressions-in-ngmodel-in-angular-js/33162197#comment60603183_33162197) to also save `false` and empty (`""`) values.

Here is an [updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wd3yKTzyy0sMGGknbVIP?p=preview)