# angularjs two-way binding inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have an Angular controller variable defining the look-and-feel of a bunch of fields which I want to render in a template.  The initial value of my underlying model correctly appears in the input element, but it doesn't change when I change the content of that element.

Here is some code:

**app.js**

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("my_app", []);
    app.controller("MyController", function() {
      var my_controller = this;
      my_controller.model = {
        "first_name": "fred",
        "last_name": "jones"
      }
      my_controller.fields = [
         {
          "name": "first_name",
          "label": "First Name",
          "is_required": true,
          "model": my_controller.model.first_name
         },
        {
          "name": "last_name",
          "label": "Last Name",
          "is_required": true,
          "model": my_controller.model.last_name
         }
       ]
})();
```

**template.html:**

```
<div ng-app="my_app">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as my_controller">
    <div ng-repeat="field in my_controller.fields">
      {% verbatim ng %}
        <label for="id_{{ field.name }}" ng-class="field.is_required ? 'required' : 'optional'">{{ field.label }}:&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="{{ field.type }}" class="form-control" name="{{ field.name }}" id="id_{{ field.name }}" ng-model="field.model">
      {% endverbatim ng %}
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*(Don't worry about the "{% verbatim ng %}" stuff - that's just there b/c I'm using Django.)*

This correctly displays two input fields with an initial value of "fred" and "jones" respectively.  But when I change the value in those fields, there is no corresponding change to the `my_controller.model` object.

Any hints?

Thanks.

Comment: why are you using `ng-repeat` when your variable `my_controller.fields` is not an array?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey - Thanks.  I have changed the example to be an array.  The error still remains, though.

Comment: What is `user_controller`? If your controller is `my_controller`.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash - Thanks.  I have changed the example.  `user_controller` was left over from the original code; This is obviously a very scaled-back example just to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @trubliphone Thanks! I've thought it was some kind of bad copy-paste :) Posted an answer meanwhile, you can try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this `"model": user_controller.model.first_name` will just assign value to the `model` field and it will not create a reference to `my_controller.model.field_name`.

You can simply use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to modify the `my_controller.model` fields:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('testController',
  function testController($scope) {
  
      var my_controller = this;
      
      my_controller.model = {
        first_name: "fred",
        last_name: "jones"
      };
      
      my_controller.fields = [
         {
          "name": "first_name",
          "label": "First Name",
          "is_required": true
         },
        {
          "name": "last_name",
          "label": "Last Name",
          "is_required": true
         }
       ];
       
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="app">
<div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="testController as my_controller">
      <div ng-repeat="field in my_controller.fields">
  
        <label for="id_{{ field.name }}" ng-class="field.is_required ? 'required' : 'optional'">{{ field.label }}:&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="{{ field.type }}" class="form-control" name="{{ field.name }}" id="id_{{ field.name }}" ng-model="my_controller.model[field.name]">

     </div>
     -----------------------------------
     <br/>
     <code>{{my_controller.model}}</code>
</div>
</body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is definitely the right direction.  My actual model is quite a bit more complex, but I'm confident I'll get it working soon and accept this answer.

Comment: Stanislav's answer is correct.  However, for very complex ng-model paths (ie: `model.submodel.submodel[23].property`), I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42562330/1060339) quite helpful.

Comment: I agree, this is for quite simple models. For more complex your mentioned answer from other post will work. Anyway, glad you was able to sort this out.